# How do I map the middle mouse button to make a double click?

Tags: 18.04, unity

Ubuntu 18.04.
When I click the middle mouse button, it should double click. 
Thanks.

EDIT: Using Unity desktop.

Comment: `xdotool click --repeat 2 1` bind this to b:2 with xbindkeys

Comment: @PRATAP Using Unity desktop, forgot that. It's not working. I think it uses wayland and not X.

Comment: Hi, So in Ubuntu 18.04 you have installed Unity desktop? `sudo apt install unity` ??

Comment: @PRATAP yes, that's correct.

Comment: I have installed unity with `sudo apt install unity` and it is xsession only not wayland. I have tried `xdotool click --repeat 2 1` binding it with letter `p` for testing purpose with xbindkeys and it worked. for b:2 I need to dig.. but unfortunetly I dont have external mice and my laptop touchpad tap to clicks are not working at all with unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS: Ubuntu 18:04
Required Packages: `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`

you can install these packages with `sudo apt install xdotool xbindkeys`

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

Paste the below content

```
"xdotool click --repeat 2 1"
b:2
```

Save the file and run `xbindkeys --poll-rc`

now your Middle Click should work as double click.

from `man xdotool` some of the content

```
   click [options] button
       Send a click, that is, a mousedown followed by mouseup for the
       given button with a short delay between the two (currently 12ms).

       Buttons generally map this way: Left mouse is 1, middle is 2, right
       is 3, wheel up is 4, wheel down is 5.

       --clearmodifiers
           Clear modifiers before clicking. See CLEARMODIFIERS below.

       --repeat REPEAT
           Specify how many times to click. Default is 1. For a double-
           click, use '--repeat 2'
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.3

---

***Workaround***

If you have installed unity like this `sudo apt install unity`

then use below content in `.xbindkeysrc` file

```
"xdotool click --repeat 2 1"
b:2 + Release
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity session.

Comment: Using Unity desktop, forgot that. It's not working. I think it uses wayland and not X.

Comment: @Chila Answer Edited. Please Review.

Comment: Works. Too bad is on release, the mouse must be steady.

Comment: Great! It works on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I've had little luck with `btnx` and `xdotool` so, if you're on `Linux Mint` or other `Ubuntu`-based distro, I would suggest [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) available on the repos:

```
sudo apt install input-remapper
```

Then, configure a desired button with the following code:

```
repeat(2, key(BTN_LEFT).w(50))
```

This will repeat the left button mouse with a 50ms delay. Using the standard `key(BTN_LEFT).key(BTN_LEFT)` did not worked for me, presumably because no `ButtonRelease` event was sent in time to be detected by cinnamon. Enjoy!